# How do I fetch data from Kinvey using Backbone JS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, kinvey

I have data stored in my Kinvey database. In the documentation, Kinvey mentions the following GET request:

```
GET /appdata/:appKey/:collectionName/:id HTTP/1.1
Host: baas.kinvey.com
Authorization: [user credentials]
```

I do not know how to encode the GET request in the actual Backbone JS program. I am new to backend programming, hence the confusion.

Comment: Can you share your tries, if any?

Comment: I haven't made nay tries because I don't really know how to implement the GET statement.